# How do you select using a range of strings in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table of vehicles with registration numbers, and want to select a subset of them that are between some user-supplied 'from' and 'to' values.

So lets say the table looks like this:

```
id       reg_num
1        DD1111
2        DD1112
3        DE2245
4        EE5678
5        EF6547
```

The SQL I have so far looks like this:

```
select *
from vehicles
where reg_num >= 'DD'   -- this value is user supplied
and reg_num <= 'DE'     -- and so is this one
```

Which should (by my thinking) return:

```
1        DD1111
2        DD1112
3        DE2245
```

But instead, only returns:

```
1        DD1111
2        DD1112
```

I imagine that SQL server sees 'DE2245' as greater than 'DE', and so excludes the row.

My question: How do I get SQL server to include all rows that start with 'DE'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
where reg_num >= @userValueFrom 
and left(reg_num,char_length(@userValueTo) <= @userValueTo
```

but please note that this where does not utilize any index because of a function on the column in SARG.

Answer (score 9):

You have to add 'zzzz's at the end as many as necessary to match your column width definition.

```
 select * from vehicles 
 where reg_num  >= 'DD' and reg_num <= 'DE' + 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
```

Comment: Or you could "increment" it to 'DF' and use <, not <=.

Comment: @Pax - that is true, I just remember seeing this in a DB2 project long time ago - funny thing is, we had to use the EBCDIC equivalent to the highest char :)

Comment: Fortunately, DB2/z can now use Unicode (although many of our customers are still holding out :-). And, whilst we get all the fancy FOSS tools for z/Linux, the z/OS UNIX system services doesn't compile half the stuff since it's still EBCDIC under the covers.

Answer (score 3):

If the format is guaranteed, you can simply do:

```
SELECT *
FROM vehicles 
WHERE LEFT(reg_num, 2) BETWEEN 'DD' AND 'DE'
```

But again, this is supposedly not SARGable - which always baffles me, because surely an  index on reg_num can be used...

Answer (score 0):

DE2245 is not less than DE. To make it more clear, DE2245 is less than DE**3**