# Query similar full text in database

Tags: python, database, algorithm, numpy, opencv

I am trying to match an OCR'd letter against a boilerplate template that will be stored in a database. I know how to compare strings to get similarity but for obvious reasons, I don't want to iterate over the entire table to compare every object. Is there a way to create an integer representation of a string so that the db could be queried with a range?

Ideally, I'd be able to take an OCR result of `This 1s a string` and within a certain threshold, find a stored value in the database of `This is a string`. The documents will be full page letters.

My second thought is to create a boilerplate table and a child table that has a hash for each line of text. I could iterate through the OCR results and query for the hash value until I have a unique result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about just changing the query statement? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505989/how-do-you-select-using-a-range-of-strings-in-sql

Comment: I don't think that would work when my input text is of unknown quality and I'm dealing with large text blobs...think like a W9 form. I would remove identified entities and other data that I can and need to be able to check against the database to match that it is indeed a W9 form with a certain confidence level.

Comment: databases don't work like that. strings don't work like that. -- you need to use any "fuzzy search" abilities of your database. don't reinvent the wheel. -- at least you should research "edit distance"... and everything related to it, or improving on it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm not trying to make a database do something it isn't designed to do. I'm familiar with how to use Levenshtein distance and cosine similarity but I can't conceive a way to use those when I have to find the correct template in a doc store of 10,000 or one million variations. With reverse image search you tag images with features and query on that, grab the results and compare the histograms to find the closest matches. I suppose that is viable for text documents too and then I could leverage Whoosh (full text search), so that may be one approach.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf -- I'm only here because you tagged OpenCV, and I don't see how that specifically relates to the question. your question starts *after* OCR, right?